# Purpose of `region` settings in ios for DateFormatters

Tags: ios, localization, dateformatter

I am aware that `DateFormatter`s use both language and region to produce the required strings/content.
And especially reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html) it seems that i understood correctly how they are supposed to work.

> Locales represent the formatting choices for a particular user, not the user’s preferred language. These are often the same but can be different. For example, a native English speaker who lives in Germany might select English as the language and Germany as the region. Text appears in English but dates, times, and numbers follow German formatting rules. The day precedes the month and a 24-hour clock represents times, as shown in Table 4-1

Then why if i set my mobile with

- Preferred System Languages: **[Spanish, Italian]**
- Region: **United States**
- and my app ONLY supports **German**

a simple (pseudocode)

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.string(from: date)`
```

returns `miércoles, 26. sept 2018` ? **(it's spanish with german region formatting)**

Considering that the bundle (and therefore all the strings returned from `NSLocalizedString(..)` and relative resources) has chosen the language properly (`de`, german), why don't the foundation objects use the same language (and not region) supported and identified by the bundle to produce the needed output and instead they stick to the system ones?

Is there some app-wise configuration i am missing or i really have to override language, locale and region for each Calendar, DateFormatter, NumberFormatter, ecc i need to use? Expecially considering how inefficient are these classes and their instantiation.

Comment: I can't find a locale and dateformatter setting that matches your above example result. I don't know what you mean by "my app ONLY supports German." In what way are you enforcing that? (Or is that the heart of the question; that you want to enforce that?) When you say "override language, locale and region," this is a bit confusing. Language and region are *part* of locale. I'm not clear about the "inefficient" comment. These objects are expensive to create, but that's the same whether or not you set an explicit locale. Is your goal to just use specific Locale throughout the app?

Comment: - They are expensive to create and as far as i know to also be changed of some properties, like `dateFormat`, i assumed may be the same for other properties.
- I said language/locale/region since i was referring to different cocoa objects with different properties, it's probably not clear sorry. 
- Override i mean just set the wanted properties
- supports DE means that in the project settings only DE is selected as supported and there are no localized resources (or if there are they are not matching the preferredLanguages)

Comment: OK, in that case, I believe my answer is what you want. If you want to lock formatters into a specific Locale, assign that Locale to the formatter. As you note, formatters are expensive to create, so you may want to cache them, but they're not *that* expensive to create, so it only matters if you're creating them a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listed several questions in the comments, and the answers may change my understanding of the question, but assuming the question is just how to make formatters format using the German language as spoken in Germany, that's just setting a Locale.

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "de-DE")
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateStyle = .full
df.locale = locale
df.string(from: Date())  // "Freitag, 28. September 2018"
```

The fact that my current Locale is en-US doesn't impact that.

It doesn't take any longer to create a DateFormatter and assign its Locale than to just create a DateFormatter. It's an extra line of code, but you can wrap that up in an extension if you like (and moreover, you may want to create shared immutable instances if you want to avoid creating them repeatedly, but that is true whether you set an explicit Locale or not).

The whole point of things like `dateStyle` is that it adapts to the user's configuration. If you don't want to adapt to the user's configuration, just configure the formatters to behave the way you want them to.

Comment: The problem maybe is more evident with `Calendar` class, which is a struct and needs to be set with the target language as well, but passing it means copying it, that is inefficient. We make HUGE use of formatters, calendars, locale, ecc. 
It's just really annoying to pay attention to the locales every time, and having many dozens of formatters, ecc. Even wrapping everything up, with many developers, and impossibility to forbid the use of cocoa formatters, it's easy to have one misused. This is what we do so far, but we keep incurring in the same silly issues over and over.

Comment: Also with more languages involved, it's not safe to assume what is the best fallback one. So i end up takeing a "region code" string from the Localizable.strings and using that as Locale. It's quite aweful.
I'm probably just expecting too much from cocoa. Well anyway thanks, i guess there isn't much to do, i'll accept in a little.